# How to run python script with depentdent shell command in the background

Tags: python, shell

Is it possible to run shell command at background in python script? Let say I have run.py and in this script I need to do,

```
#run shell command(in python script until script is finished)
#continue with  script
```

But the problem is that they are dependent. To run my script I need to run shell command in the same script.

Comment: What's the shell command that you're running? And can you add some detail about what you mean by the two tasks being "dependent"? A concrete example might help.

Comment: my shell comment is
    `docker run -it -p 9563:9563 --rm -v "$PWD":/config-dir logstash-cont -f /config-dir/logstashConf.config`

In my script I am sending data to logstash

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `subprocess` library in Python and check the status of the output.

Ex: `subprocess.check_call("exit 1", shell=True)`

Comment: This is not what I want. Shell command is running forever. I can use something like:
 `docker run -it -p 9563:9563 --rm -v "$PWD":/config-dir logstash-cont -f /config-dir/logstashConf.config & client.py` on shell but I need to do this  in client.py. But If I say to python run this shell code, it will wait until termination. I want to run shell command and continue with python script.